# Can Emacs differentiate between ctrl-r and ctrl-shift-r?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I'd like to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to `'isearch-backward` and bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to `'tags-apropos` but I can't distinguish between the two key presses.

Can emacs differentiate between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>?  What should go into my .emacs file to allow this keybinding?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-r") 'isearch-backward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-r") 'tags-apropos)
```

The way to figure out the answer to this kind of question is to do help on a key <kbd>C-h k</kbd>, and type the keystrokes you're interested in.  What Emacs shows in the *Help* buffer is the string you can pass to the macro `'kbd`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- one is `"\C-r"`, the other is `"\C-R"`.  They can easily be bound to separate commands.  For example, this should do the trick if placed in your `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key "\C-R" 'tags-apropos)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  When you pass a string to global-set-key, any uppercase character gets translated to its lowercase equivalent. So (global-set-key "\C-R" 'tags-apropos) will actually bind Ctrl + r, not Ctrl + Shift + r.

To work around this translation, you can use the 'kbd macro, as the other answer states.