# How to make Emacs (without GUI) differentiate between Ctrl+Shift+S and Ctrl+S?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to teach Emacs standard shortcut keys. I use emacs23-nox version from Debian, often through SSH connection. One of those is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for *SaveAs*. The relevant part of configuration looks like this:

```
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-S") 'write-file)
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'save-buffer)
```

but causes either both <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> invoke `'save-buffer` (or `'write-file`, depending on which line comes last). I also tried `"C-S-s"` instead of `"C-S"`.

*No Use of Shift Key* section of [*Why Emacs's Keyboard Shortcuts Are Painful*](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_kb_shortcuts_pain.html) says it's not possible. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858713/can-emacs-differentiate-between-ctrl-r-and-ctrl-shift-r), but the accepted solution doesn't work for me (C-h k <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> prints C-s).

Is there a way to make Emacs (the no GUI version) differentiate between <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, there isn't any provision in the character sets for uppercase control characters. The only way you can get shift *and* control is by going direct to the windowing system, so you need the GUI version.

Comment: On a related note, it is a good idea to bind keys with shift and control to commands that require GUI. Because unbound keys are scarce resource in terminal Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a bit: If you are using Emacs with a window manager, then you can bind the key `[(control shift ?s)]`, which is <kbd>C-S-s</kbd> (aka <kbd>C-S</kbd>, but not written this way in Emacs). This key is definitely different from the ASCII control character `C-s`, which has no lowercase/uppercase versions.

So the answer is (a) you have to be using a graphics terminal; (b) bind `[(control shift ?s)]` to get the uppercase version.