# Shifted command ignored when unshifted version exists

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I have the following bindings:

```
M-q   => fill-paragraph
M-S-q => unfill-paragraph
```

But either key combo results in the first: `fill-paragraph`, so it
appears that the `Shift` and thus
[unfill](https://github.com/purcell/unfill) is ignored.  I set the
second myself:

```
(prelude-require-package 'unfill)
(define-key prelude-mode-map "\M-\S-q" nil)  ; don't let prelude dictate it
(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-q") 'unfill-paragraph)
```

There is a behavior of Emacs to fall back to an unshifted sequence
when the shifted version does not exist (this seems good, but should
not be happening for this case).  So if I didn't have the `M-S-q`
binding, then pressing that should result in `fill-paragraph`, which
is what I'm unhappily seeing.  This suggests that somehow Emacs
doesn't know about the second binding.  But I've verified that it does
know with `C-h f unfill-paragraph` confirming it.  Invoking from
`M-x` shows it working well.

Why is the `Shift` being ignored?

(This is the GUI version of Emacs and my Shift keys work fine for other
things.)

Comment: how about `(global-set-key (kbd "M-Q") 'unfill-paragraph)`

Comment: Thanks, I think that is working. Wow. But it's annoying since I've seen use of `C-S-` in several places (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858713/can-emacs-differentiate-between-ctrl-r-and-ctrl-shift-r), and I like that it's explicit.

Comment: n.b. This is effectively a duplicate of [Why the key binding M-S-t fails while C-S-t works?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38180797/324105) (which see for some explanation/speculation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs has some confusing problems w.r.t handling of shift, since the shift modifier is sometimes treated like a normal modifier but other times is special-cased to modify the base char so it's upper-cased.

In this case, I think you'll need `?\M-Q`.  In contrast, `?\C-Q` is the same as `?\C-q` so you need to use `?\C-S-q` to bind something to C-S-q.

This probably deserves a `M-x report-emacs-bug`.